# Query database to find all records that matches my search criteria

Tags: grails

`Person` domain class is as follows:

```
String name
String gender
boolean available
double salary
```

What i want to do is to query the database to find out all the `Person`'s who are available and increase their `salary` by 100.

```
def person = new Person()
// now i need to get the count of available person
```

I think i have to use `Person.executeQuery("THE QUERY")`, but i don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do something like this:

```
Person.executeUpdate('update Person p set p.salary = p.salary+100 where p.available = :available', [available: true])
```

Or:

```
Person.executeUpdate('update Person p set p.salary = p.salary+100 where p.available = TRUE')
```

I hope that helps.